# How do I separate two integers from a string of those two integers?

Tags: python, string, integer

I have an outside file. The last line of the file contains two numbers. I was able to get a string of the two numbers by:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    width = file.readline()
    for column in file:
        pass
```

now I am left with the two numbers as a string that reads "1 10".
I need to access the 10 of that string.
I have used: `print(re.findall('\d+', column))` which just gave me ['1', '10'] but I really only need the integer 10 for the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: Look into the ‘split’ function for this

Comment: `['1', '10'][1] == '10'`

Comment: _I have used: `print(re.findall('\d+', column))` which just gave me ['1', '10'] but I really only need the integer 10 for the purpose of the assignment._ You can extract only the element you want from the list then, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the last line of a file, you can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
last_line = ''
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        last_line = line

parts = last_line.split()   # split on whitespaces
print(parts[1])             # print second element
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the split() function.

```
width = width.split(' ')[-1]
```

`width` is your string variable ('['1', '10']']. Usually you rather want to use split() instead of regex because of performance.